# updating dataframe based on lookup from any column to any column in other dataframe

Tags: r

I'm recoding faulty imported country data based on reference ISO country codes.

Here's a sample of rows from imported df "Countries":

```
                     country country_code2      country_code3  USCandidate USActual
1              United States            US                USA         TRUE     TRUE
37                    Canada            CA                CAN        FALSE    FALSE    
60                       CAN                             <NA>        FALSE    FALSE
304544                              Brazil                 BR        FALSE    FALSE
321170 Saint-Martin (France)            MF                MAF        FALSE    FALSE
343687             Karnataka            19                           FALSE    FALSE
```

Values can be jumbled, missing or NA. The last two columns should be ignored.

Here are the first rows of reference df "CountriesISO":

```
            Name Alpha2 Alpha3 Numeric
1    Afghanistan     AF    AFG   "004"
2  Aland Islands     AX    ALA   "248"
3        Albania     AL    ALB   "008"
4        Algeria     DZ    DZA   "012"
5 American Samoa     AS    ASM   "016"
6        Andorra     AD    AND   "020"
```

I want to match the values of any of the first three columns of df "Countries" to the values of any of the first three columns of "CountriesISO" and append the matching "Alpha3" value to a new column "Alpha3" in "Countries". For the sample given, the resulting df "Countries" should look like (I've omitted the columns already provided above):

```
       [1:5] Alpha3
1      [...]    USA
37     [...]    CAN
60     [...]    CAN
304544 [...]    BRA
321170 [...]    MAF
343687 [...]
```

All samples rows can be matched to a reference country, except the last row where "Alpha3" is consequently left blank.

The closest I've been able to come is the following code:

```
apply(Countries[,1:3], 
      1, 
      function(r) CountriesISO[min(which(
        r == CountriesISO[,1]|r == CountriesISO[,2]|r == CountriesISO[,3])),3])
```

This returns a vector of mostly correct "Alpha3" values, but with lots of warnings and missing values for rows which should have been matched (e.g. the first "USA"). I need to fill in the missing values and append them to "Countries", and hopefully this can be done also with more readable and elegant code.

Comment: if the data is jumbled as you show here then doing analysis is time waste! why don't you clean the data first and later ask the question! Please take this comment in a positive manner! Data is the most important element in analysis right!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. Actually, this is what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't change my problem by much. For example, if I go one "source" column at a time in df "Countries", I still need to look up a value in any of the three first columns of df  "CountriesISO". I haven't found code in stackoverflow that looks up a value in "any column". I guess I can manually do each "target" column at a time. That's a combination of 9 operations.